# Delete property and its values in all the object

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in javaScript, I have this object MyGraph:

```
const MyGraph = {
    a: { b: 5, c: 2 },
    b: { a: 5, c: 7, d: 8 },
    c: { a: 2, b: 7, d: 4, e: 8 },
};
```

I want to delete property "a" and its values in other properties as well to get this result:

```
const MyGraph = {
    b: { c: 7, d: 8 },
    c: { b: 7, d: 4, e: 8 },
};
```

I tried like this:

```
for(let XXX of Object.keys(MyGraph)){
    console.log(XXX.a);
    delete XXX.a;
}
```

the result of execution:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

any help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a key from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455405/how-do-i-remove-a-key-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: duplicate: [Javascript delete nested object properties by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62895132/javascript-delete-nested-object-properties-by-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a recursive algorithm :

```js
function del_entries(key, obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    delete obj[key];
  }

  // Or with Object.hasOwn, not fully supported by old browsers but more up to date
 /*
 if (Object.hasOwn(obj, key)) {
     delete obj[key]
 }
 */
  
  Object.values(obj).forEach(o=> del_entries(key, o))
}


const MyGraph = {
    a: { b: 5, c: 2 },
    b: { a: 5, c: 7, d: 8 },
    c: { a: 2, b: 7, d: 4, e: 8 },
};

del_entries("a", MyGraph);

console.log(MyGraph)
```

Comment: you can now recommend the new [`hasOwn()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) which takes care of the [issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn#problematic_cases_for_hasownproperty) with `hasOwnProperty`

Answer (score 1):

In your code `XXX` is the key. You need to do `graph[XXX]` to access the actual object. So instead of `XXX.a` you should do `graph[XXX].a`. But this only accounts for objects in `graph` that have an the key `a`. You also need to account for key `a` in `graph`. Please see the code below. Its a rudimentary example.

If you have one level of nesting then you can use then you can use the code below.

```js
const mygraph = {
  a: { b: 5, c: 2 },
  b: { a: 5, c: 7, d: 8 },
  c: { a: 2, b: 7, d: 4, e: 8 },
};

console.log(mygraph);

function deletePropAndValuesOf(key, graph) {

  for (const k of Object.keys(graph)) {
    if (k === key) {
      delete graph[key];
    } else {
      if (key in graph[k]) {
        delete graph[k][key]
      }
    }
  }
}

deletePropAndValuesOf("a", graph);

console.log(mygraph);
```

You can copy the code to a `.js` file and run it using node. e.g.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Ive used object destructuring to remove the first array with an a, but could not figure out how to do all the a's's but the code below might help?

```
const MyGraph = {
a: { b: 5, c: 2 },
b: { a: 5, c: 7, d: 8 },
c: { a: 2, b: 7, d: 4, e: 8 }};
const {a, ...newMyGraph} = MyGraph;
// output
console.log(newMyGraph)
```

returns

```
b: {
   a: 5,
   c: 7,
   d: 8
},
c: {
   a: 2,
   b: 7,
   d: 4,
   e: 8
}
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, and the thought to use destructuring is interesting because it avoids mutating the original. To make it work for the OP's question you'll need to employ recursion, which is a little more complicated than the other answers because of the cloning effect at play. See an example here: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lumh4yfk/1/)